# Query Split string into rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, split, rows, delimiter

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID    Value
1     1,10
2     7,9
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
ID   Value
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
1    5
1    6
1    7
1    8
1    9
1    10
2    7
2    8
2    9
```

I'm after both a range between `2` numbers with `,` as the delimiter (there can only be one delimiter in the value) and how to split this into rows.

Comment: You should change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column

Comment: you are right but for this case the user is the one typing in the values and i don´t want the user to type this 10 times for the first rown and 3 for the second

Comment: It is a difference what a user inputs and what you store in the DB. And you can at least seperate the 2 values in 2 columns. And then use your program logic to create the list.

Answer (score 5):

Splitting the comma separated numbers is a small part of this problem.  The parsing should be done in the application and the range stored in separate columns.  For more than one reason:  Storing numbers as strings is a bad idea.  Storing two attributes in a single column is a bad idea.  And, actually, storing unsanitized user input in the database is also often a bad idea.

In any case, one way to generate the list of numbers is to use a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, cast(left(value, charindex(',', value) - 1) as int) as first,
             cast(substring(value, charindex(',', value) + 1, 100) as int) as last
      from table t
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.id, t.first as value, t.last
      from t
      union all
      select cte.id, cte.value + 1, cte.last
      from cte
      where cte.value < cte.last
     )
select id, value
from cte
order by id, value;
```

You may need to fiddle with the value of `MAXRECURSION` if the ranges are really big.

Answer (score 0):

Any table that a field with multiple values such as this is a problem in terms of design. The only way to deal with these records as it is is to split the values on the delimiter and put them into a temporary table, implement custom splitting code, integrate a CTE as noted, or redesign the original table to put the comma-delimited fields into separate fields, eg

```
ID LOWLIMIT HILIMIT
1  1        10
```

Comment: Does not answer the question of how to produce the desired result.  Does not even answer the question on how to split.  A temporary table is not the only solution.

Comment: Understand and respect your point, but also I think part of what is done at SO is to discourage solutions fostered by poor fundamental design choices. I can't see this database design as anything other than that.

Comment: But this is NOT a solution.  Answers are for answers.  As a comment it is already covered.  Even split in two columns you don't answer the question of how to produce the desired output.   Your assertion the only fix is temporary table is just plain wrong - see answer from Linoff.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I have amended my answer to include the CTE option Linoff has noted. We will have to agree to disagree on the issue of an answer. Sometimes, redesigning IS the right answer.

Comment: @Blam I assure you I did not downvote anything. I appreciate your perspective and have no problem with constructive disagreement. No retaliation here.

Comment: See the posted guidelines for answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that"

Answer (score 0):

similar with `Gordon Linoff` variant, but has some difference

```
--create temp table for data sample
DECLARE @Yourdata AS TABLE ( id INT, VALUE VARCHAR(20) )
INSERT  @Yourdata
        ( id, VALUE )
VALUES  ( 1, '1,10' ),
        ( 2, '7,9' )
--final query
;WITH    Tally
          AS ( SELECT   MIN(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(y.VALUE, 1, CHARINDEX(',', y.value) - 1))) AS MinV ,
                        MAX(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(y.VALUE, CHARINDEX(',', y.value) + 1, 18))) AS MaxV
               FROM     @yourdata AS y
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   MinV = MinV + 1 , MaxV
               FROM     Tally
               WHERE    MinV < Maxv
             )
    SELECT  y.id , t.minV AS value
    FROM    @yourdata AS y
            JOIN tally AS t ON t.MinV BETWEEN CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(y.VALUE, 1, CHARINDEX(',', y.value) - 1))
                                      AND     CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(y.VALUE, CHARINDEX(',', y.value) + 1, 18))
    ORDER BY id, minV
OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 999 ) --change it if required
```

*output*

[image]